# Pandas: new boolean column when at least N other boolean columns are True

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with several boolean columns. I want to create a new column which is True when at least N of those columns are True. For example:

```
Name | A | B | C | D
John Doe | False | True | False | True
Jane Smith | True | False | False | False
Alan Holmes | True | False | True | True
Eric Lamar | True | True | True | True
```

For `N=2`, we would get a column with values: `(True, False, True, True)`

Is there any pythonic way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df['New'] = df.select_dtypes(bool).sum(axis=1).ge(N)
print (df)
          Name      A      B      C      D    New
0     John Doe  False   True  False   True   True
1   Jane Smith   True  False  False  False  False
2  Alan Holmes   True  False   True   True   True
3   Eric Lamar   True   True   True   True   True
```

**Detail**:

First select only boolean columns by [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html):

```
print (df.select_dtypes(bool))
       A      B      C      D
0  False   True  False   True
1   True  False  False  False
2   True  False   True   True
3   True   True   True   True
```

Count only `True`s by [`DataFrame.sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) - `True`s are processes like `1`:

```
print (df.select_dtypes(bool).sum(axis=1))
0    2
1    1
2    3
3    4
dtype: int64
```

Test by [`Series.ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html) for `>=`:

```
print (df.select_dtypes(bool).sum(axis=1).ge(N))
0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `pandas.DataFrame.sum(1)`:

```
N = 2
df['Trues'] = df.iloc[:, 1:].sum(1)>=N

         Name      A      B      C      D  Trues
0     JohnDoe  False   True  False   True   True
1   JaneSmith   True  False  False  False  False
2  AlanHolmes   True  False   True   True   True
3   EricLamar   True   True   True   True   True
```